# I need to create a 3 D rotating box in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c, 3d, rotation

I need to create a 3D rotating box(cube) using objective-c.I have gone through several tutorials but do not know how to go with them properly to get something like this..

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1zjbglmveg02364/cover17.zip?dl=0

Can someone guide how to use CAlayer or UIView with CATransform3DRotate & CATransform3DTranslate to achieve this?

Comment: There is SceneKit which lets you load 3D objects and rotate them. Here's a tutorial: http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/scene-kit-primitives-tutorial-swift

Comment: I have checked it but i could not figure out if there is some way to add text on faces of cube.

Comment: Just add the text as a texture to your cube ? (this is leading to a second question).

Answer (score 3):

four face cube:

```
CATransform3D pt = CATransform3DIdentity;
pt.m34 = -1.0 / 500.0;
self.containerView.layer.sublayerTransform = pt;

_cubeLayer = [CATransformLayer layer];

CALayer *face1 = [CALayer layer];
face1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
face1.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
face1.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(face1.transform, 0, 0, 50);
[_cubeLayer addSublayer:face1];

CALayer *face2 = [CALayer layer];
face2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor].CGColor;
face2.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
face2.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(face2.transform, 0, 50, 0);
face2.transform = CATransform3DRotate(face2.transform, M_PI / 2, 1, 0, 0);
[_cubeLayer addSublayer:face2];

CALayer *face3 = [CALayer layer];
face3.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor].CGColor;
face3.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
face3.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(face3.transform, 0, -50, 0);
face3.transform = CATransform3DRotate(face3.transform, M_PI / 2, 1, 0, 0);
[_cubeLayer addSublayer:face3];

CALayer *face4 = [CALayer layer];
face4.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
face4.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);
face4.transform = CATransform3DTranslate(face4.transform, 0, 0, -50);
[_cubeLayer addSublayer:face4];


_cubeLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100);

[self.containerView.layer addSublayer:_cubeLayer];
```

rotate:

```
self.cubeLayer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(_cubeLayer.transform, M_PI / 2, 1, 0, 0);
```

result:
[image]